Installing Codeium plugin in VS Code - it is apparently installed and I am logged in but it is not working
Installing Codeium  plugin in VS Code - it is apparently installed and I am logged in but it is not working - that is it is not prompting when coding.
It had worked fine up until recently - I am not sure if I have done something to change the behaviour of the plugin, but I think not.
The running extension lists includes Codeium 1.8.36
I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS Code version 1.89.1 running on ubuntu 22.04 with the same result - it does not prompt when coding.
Below is the output for the plugin
2024-05-11 12:54:31.582 [INFO]: No proxy settings found
2024-05-11 12:54:31.713 [INFO]: Creating manager directory: /tmp/703ad5b1-38d0-411d-b4e5-0c3174abc9e0/codeium/manager
2024-05-11 12:54:31.715 [INFO]: 6b19fd56d85774d39e487f63cbc17e220b37637d not found, downloading language server
2024-05-11 12:54:31.717 [INFO]: No proxy settings found
2024-05-11 12:54:34.952 [ERROR]: Failed to download from https://github.com/Exafunction/codeium/releases/download/language-server-v1.8.36/language_server_linux_x64.gz
2024-05-11 12:54:34.969 [ERROR]: Language server binary not found: undefined

thankyou

This may be due to your network issues, you can see that the codeium failed to download the file in the output.
My suggestion is as follows:
Option 1: Configure vscode's proxy and then try again.
Option 2: Manually download the file in the output and place it in the directory outputted in the output.
